# Tortoise SVN commit log message

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Source code is merged from other repository, at the time of commit how we can make default log commit message as the revision number it is merged from in TortoiseSVN client
[image: SVN Log Message]

Comment: Upgrade your TortoiseSVN client.

Comment: We are using TortoiseSVN 1.8.8 and can this be achieved by SVN Property setting

Comment: We have upgraded the tortoise SVN client 1.9.4 and the merged revision is available in log Template. But, we want that to be the default log message